# Resizing Path element to match the dimensions of image - Silverlight

Tags: c#, image, silverlight, resize

I have an image element in one xaml that is accessed and displayed on a different xaml. Interestingly the image automatically resizes itself to fit the grid while also maintaining the aspect ratio.

However I have Path elements that serve as borders to the images. When the Path elements are displayed they display at their normal size and I just cannot get them fit the image as borders no matter how I set the dimensions, whether it's programmatically or in xaml. These Path elements are imported from an Adobe Illustrator file.

This is how the code from XAML files looks,

```
    <ImageDisplay.xaml>
         <grid>
              <image name="imageToDisplay"/>
         </grid>
    </ImageDisplay.xaml>

    <ImageBorder.xaml>
         <Path Element 1>
         <Path Element 2>
         <Path Element 3>
         <Path Element 4>
    </ImageBorder.xaml>

    <SubMain.xaml>
         <local:ImageDisplay />
         <local:ImageBorder />
         <otherelements />
    </SubMain.xaml>

    <Main.xaml>
         <SubMain.xaml />
         <SubMain.xaml />
         <SubMain.xaml />
    </Main.xaml>
```

So in the Main.xaml the SubMain.xaml is allotted a certain width and height and the ImageDisplay elements re-size and fit themselves perfectly without the help of code. But the same does not happen for ImageBorder element. What might I be doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ActualWidth` and `ActualHeight` of the image after it autoresizes and set the width and height of paths.
[Image class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.controls.image%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)
[Path class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.shapes.path%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)